# jQuery Tooltip - Display dynamic content from cell data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I have spreadsheet data that is being parsed into a table. Is it possible to have jquery tooltip display data from another cell on hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
$( function() {
  $( 'td' ).on( 'mouseover', function() {
    $( this ).attr( 'title', $( this ).next().text() || $( this ).text() )
  } )

  $( document ).tooltip();
} );
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ddd
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```